Pandas to_sql: "Year (NVARCHAR(255)) not a string" Error with SQLAlchemy and PyODBC
I'm trying to load data from a CSV file into a SQL Server database using Pandas, SQLAlchemy, and PyODBC in Python. I've encountered an issue where I'm consistently getting the error:

Year (NVARCHAR(255)) not a string.

Here’s a breakdown of my setup and what I’ve tried so far:
Code Details:
Connection Setup:
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import urllib
import pyodbc 
import sqlalchemy

server = r'AAAAAPBIDEV\DATA'
database = 'NNN'
username = 'ETL_Login'
password = '123'

connection_string = (
    f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};"
    f"SERVER={server};"
    f"DATABASE={database};"
    f"UID={username};"
    f"PWD={password};"
)
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
dbEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")

Data Loading and Processing:
api_logs = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["API_Name","Created_date","Python_error","Response_text","Response_code"])    
api_names = ["GASTAT_API"]
api_urls = ["https://open.data.gov.sa/data/api/datasets/resources?version=-1&dataset=b4a20430-9335-48bd-ae89-8f7c15f16c7d"]


for api_name , api_link in zip(api_names,api_urls):
    try:
        response = r.get(api_link, verify=False)           
        data = response.json()                            
        status_code=response.status_code
        status_description=response.reason                 
        default_error=None
        csv_resource = next((resource for resource in data['resources'] if resource['format'] == 'CSV'), None)

        if csv_resource:
            url = csv_resource['downloadUrl']
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}

            try:
                urlData = r.get(url, headers=headers).content #Use r.get here as well
                rawData = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(urlData))

                translation_dict = {
                    'السنة': 'Year',
                    'الربع': 'Quarter',
                    'رمز المؤشر': 'IndexCode',
                    'اسم المؤشر': 'IndexName',
                    'نوع النشاط': 'ActivityType',
                    'رمز البند': 'ItemCode',
                    'البند': 'Item',
                    'القيمة': 'Value'
                }

                rawData.rename(columns=translation_dict, inplace=True)

Saving to Database:
 if api_name == "GASTAT_API":
                    rawData.to_sql('GASTAT_ind', schema='dbo', con= dbEngine ,  dtype={ #Use rawData here
                        'Year': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'Quarter': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'IndexCode': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'IndexName': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'ActivityType': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'ItemCode': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'Item': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(255),
                        'Value': sqlalchemy.types.Float
                    } , if_exists = 'replace', index = False)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f'an error occured with error : {str(e)}')
                default_error = e

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'an error occured with error : {str(e)}')
        default_error = e
    
    finally:
        current_log = {
            "API_Name": api_name ,
            "Created_date": pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%m/%d/%Y") ,
            "Python_error": default_error,
            "Response_text":status_description,
            "Response_code":status_code }
        
        api_logs = api_logs.append(current_log, ignore_index=True)  


api_logs.to_sql('APi_logs', schema='dbo', con = dbEngine ,  dtype = {
                         'API_Name':sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(),
                         'Created_date':sqlalchemy.types.DateTime(),
                         'Python_error': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(),
                         'Response_text': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(),
                         'Response_code': sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER()}, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)

What I've Tried:

Converted the Year column to string using astype(str) in Pandas.
Checked the data types of the DataFrame to ensure Year is of type object.
Verified that my SQLAlchemy and PyODBC installations are up-to-date.
Ensured that the connection string is correctly URL-encoded.
Problem:
Despite these efforts, I still encounter the error indicating that Year is not being recognized as a string. What steps can I take to resolve this data type mismatch so that my DataFrame is correctly inserted into the SQL Server database?


Wild guess... have you tried adding the encoding=utf_8_sig parameter to Pandas' read_csv() function yet? The referenced CSV file starts with a UTF-8 preamble/byte order mark (the bytes EF BB BF) which could be getting included in the name of the first column (which is Year in this case).
